# Mostrar lista de productos, uno al lado del otro

Tags: html, css

Me sucede que se me desordenó la lista de productos. Anteriormente estaba ordenado un producto al lado del otro, pero por alguna razón se me desacomodó y no logro encontrar el error.

[image: ADJUNTO EJEMPLO]

```css
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    h1{
        font: bold 20px verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    h2{
        font: bold 14px verdana, sans-serif;
    }        
    header, section, footer, aside, nav, 
    article, figure, figcaption,hgroup{
        display: block;
    }
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
    #titulo{
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    #logo{
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .agrupar{
        background: #000000;
    }
    article{
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 35px;
        margin-right: 35px;
        width: 1125px;
    }
    .menu{
        width: 80vw;
        background: #000000;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font-size: 22px;
        float: bottom;
        border: white 2px solid;
        
    }
    .menu ul{
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left:50px;

    }
    .menu ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: none;
        color: white; 
    }
    .menu ul li:hover{
        color: black;
        background: rgb(66, 66, 66);
        padding-left:50px;
    }

    #productos img{
        width: auto;
    }
    .card{
        border-radius: 4px ;
        background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width: 260px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #product-h{
        font-size: 17px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    p{
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .item{
        padding: 1em;
        margin: 1em;
        float: left;
    }
    .container{
        
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif ;
        font-weight: 400;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    footer{
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
        }
        .menu-footer{
            display: block;
        }
        .metodo.pagos{
            display: block;
        }
    .nav-item{
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<!-- START SECTION STORE -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">CATALOGO DE PRODUCTOS</h1>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </header>

<template id="template-card">
        <div class="col-12 mb-2 cold-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5>titulo</h5>
                    <p>price</p>
                    <button id="btn btn-dark addToCart">Añadir al carrito</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/aceite-oliva.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">ACEITE OLIVA EXTRA VIRGEN</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">$899,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart"  data-id="1">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/picada-internacional.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">PICADA P/ 2/4/6/8/10 PERSONAS</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">Desde $2300,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart"  data-id="2">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/jamon-cocido-comun.jpg" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">JAMON COCIDO NATURAL</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">$200,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart"  data-id="3">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/soppressata.jpg" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">SOPPRESSATA</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">$250,00</p> 
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart"  data-id="4">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/Rutini_Merlot.jpg" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">RUTTINI MERLOT</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">$1850,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart" data-id="5">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4" class="item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="item-image" src="../Multimedia/queso-gruyere.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="item-title">QUESO GRUYERE</h3>
            <div class="item-detail">
            <p class="item-price">$220,00</p>
            <button class="btn btn-dark addToCart" data-id="6">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de agregar ruido a la pregunta (porque es más código que texto), procura siempre describir mejor el problema en cuestión. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por cierto, si estás usando Bootstrap, es `col`, no `cold`. Incluye además en las etiquetas la versión que estás utilizando.